# Unable to populate RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Full Code link : https://github.com/sudhishkr/Flicks/tree/feature/stackoverflow

I am trying to build a movie information display app. I am trying to use `recyclerview` and that seems to not load my data after a network call.

My MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewTheMovieDB;
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapterTheMovieDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerViewTheMovieDB = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTheMovieDB);
        recyclerViewAdapterTheMovieDB = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerViewTheMovieDB.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerViewTheMovieDB.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterTheMovieDB);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test2);
        VolleyCallback callback = new VolleyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccessResponse(ArrayList<Movie> result) {
                try {
                    recyclerViewAdapterTheMovieDB.setMovieList(result);
                    textView.setText(result.get(0).getTitle());
                } catch (Exception e){

                }
                return;
            }
        };
        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        TheMovieDBApi theMovieDBApiObj = new TheMovieDBApi();
        theMovieDBApiObj.getMovieList(queue, getApplicationContext(), callback);

    }
}
```

My RecyclerViewAdapter :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolderTheMovieDB>{


    private ArrayList<Movie> listMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public void setMovieList(ArrayList<Movie> listMovies){
        this.listMovies = listMovies;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, listMovies.size());
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context){
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolderTheMovieDB onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_inflater_themoviedb, parent, false);
        ViewHolderTheMovieDB viewHolderTheMovieDB = new ViewHolderTheMovieDB(view);
        return viewHolderTheMovieDB;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderTheMovieDB holder, int position) {
        Movie currentMovie = listMovies.get(position);
        try {
            holder.title.setText(currentMovie.getTitle());
            holder.overview.setText(currentMovie.getOverview());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listMovies.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolderTheMovieDB extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView title;
        private TextView overview;

        public ViewHolderTheMovieDB(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            overview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOverview);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code - the `notifyDataSetChanged` or the `notifyItemRangeChanged` doesn't seem to fill the recycler view.

I am also setting my `textview` with the first item, and that seems to work. I am having a hard time trying to figure out what is going wrong with my `RecyclerView`. Any help/direction would be great.

Comment: u dont need notifyItemRangeChanged at all. 'Cause u re calling notifyDataSetChanged already. remove it and try again.

Comment: I left both over there because I couldn't get it to work with either or both.

Comment: did u check if the array is not empty?